# Creating samples after sample without duplicates using itertools and list comprehensions

Tags: python, list-comprehension, combinations, python-itertools, sampling

Looking for a more efficient way to achieve a desired result.  Combinations is first used to create a list of items taken two at a time:

combos = itertools.combinations(range(1,6),2)
b=list(combos)

> [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 5)]

Starting with the first firsts tuple (1,2), I need to identify which other 2-tuple can be used to create a 4 tuple where the 2nd tuple has no elements in common with the first.  (Akin to sampling two players for one team, and two for another).

The desired result is a maximum set of 4 tuples from the list (b) above, where all there are no duplicates.   Note For this exercise:  (3,4,1,2) is a duplicate of (1,2,3,4). Continuing with the team analogy, it is because the opponents are the same: (1,2) vs. (3,4). Effectively cuts the list in half.

The code below creates the desired output:

```
x = [(b[i][0], b[i][1], b[j][0], b[j][1])
     for i in range(0,len(b))
     for j in range(i+1,len(b))
     if b[i][0] != b[j][0]
     and b[i][0] != b[j][1]
     and b[i][1] != b[j][0]
     and b[i][1] != b[j][1]]
```

> [(1, 2, 3, 4),
> (1, 2, 3, 5),
> (1, 2, 4, 5),
> (1, 3, 2, 4),
> (1, 3, 2, 5),
> (1, 3, 4, 5),
> (1, 4, 2, 3),
> (1, 4, 2, 5),
> (1, 4, 3, 5),
> (1, 5, 2, 3),
> (1, 5, 2, 4),
> (1, 5, 3, 4),
> (2, 3, 4, 5),
> (2, 4, 3, 5),
> (2, 5, 3, 4)]

Got the right result Choose(5,2) X Choose (3,2) cut in half for 10 * 3 /2 = 15 4-tuples.

I wanted to get the communities input if there is possibly a better way to generate the list.  Clunky, but it works.  Cheers and Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can generate all unique 4-tuples and add permutations:

```
idxs = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 2, 1, 3], [0, 3, 1, 2]]
result = list()

for comb in itertools.combinations(range(1, 6), 4):
  for idx in idxs:
    result.append(tuple([comb[i] for i in idx]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate these lazily (so minimal memory is needed) and without needing to filter duplicates by iterating over combinations of length `4` instead of pairs of combinations of length `2`.

Suppose you have an ordered list of 4 numbers: `a < b < c < d`. These 4 numbers will be part of exactly 3 results in the answer: `a` will be first, and we have 3 choices for the second number, after which the last two numbers must go in order.

Then just use [itertools.chain()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) for lazy evaluation:

```py
ans = itertools.chain.from_iterable(
        (((a, b, c, d),
          (a, c, b, d),
          (a, d, b, c))
         for a, b, c, d in itertools.combinations(range(1, 6), 4)))
```

producing:

```
(1, 2, 3, 4)
(1, 3, 2, 4)
(1, 4, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 3, 5)
(1, 3, 2, 5)
(1, 5, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 4, 5)
(1, 4, 2, 5)
(1, 5, 2, 4)
(1, 3, 4, 5)
(1, 4, 3, 5)
(1, 5, 3, 4)
(2, 3, 4, 5)
(2, 4, 3, 5)
(2, 5, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Both @kcsquared and @hilberts_drinking_problem's answers hard-codes permutations specifically for 4 selected players, which is hardly ideal if the number of players in a match can vary.

A more generic solution to the problem of any even number of players would be to ensure the uniqueness of the outputting teams by first setting apart a specific player from the players picked for a match and then picking teammates for it. Those that are not its teammates are on the other team, which we can find out by using the `set.difference` method:

```
from itertools import combinations

# produces unique matches of m players from a pool of n players
def matches(n, m):
    for first, *rest in combinations(range(1, n + 1), m):
        for teammates in combinations((rest := set(rest)), m // 2 - 1):
            yield first, *teammates, *rest.difference(teammates)

print(*matches(5, 4), sep='\n')
```

This efficiently outputs:

```
(1, 2, 3, 4)
(1, 3, 2, 4)
(1, 4, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 3, 5)
(1, 3, 2, 5)
(1, 5, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 4, 5)
(1, 4, 2, 5)
(1, 5, 2, 4)
(1, 3, 4, 5)
(1, 4, 3, 5)
(1, 5, 3, 4)
(2, 3, 4, 5)
(2, 4, 3, 5)
(2, 5, 3, 4)
```